# Is there a way to see all static variables and methods of a class in Typescript or ES6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Similar to the Object.keys method which will return a list of all the key names attached to an object, is there a way to return all static variable names and all the static method names attached to a class?

Typescript Example:

```
class FindStatics {
  static num1:string = 'Num 1';
  static num2:string = 'Num 2';
  notStatic:string = "I'm not static";
  static concat ():string {
    return `${FindStatics.num1} loves ${FindStatics.num2}`
  }
  addToNonStatic(str:string):string {
    return `${this.notStatic} + ${str}`;
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is get the names of only the static variable and method names; so in the above example I would like `num1`, `num2`, and `concat` returned.

Comment: These are not "variables". They are "properties".

Answer (score 9):

So as it turns out, you can just use the `Object.keys` method to get a list of all the static variable and method names attached to a class.  ES6 classes are mostly just syntactical sugar to ES5.  All static properties are inherited by the class, this also works for subclassing as well, we actually get a real prototype link between a subclass constructor function and the superclass constructor.

Therefore to return all static variable and method names for the example:

```
Object.keys(FindStatics);
```

Answer (score 3):

@Kirkify, `Object.keys` doesn't return names of methods in my browser, because they're not enumerable.

[image: method names are not returned from Object.keys]

For anyone who stumbles upon it, `getOwnPropertyNames` can be the solution.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(FindStatics) === [
  "length", "prototype", "concat", "name", "num1", "num2"
]

const lengthPrototypeAndName = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(class {})
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(FindStatics).filter(
  k => !lengthPrototypeAndName.includes(k)
) === ["concat", "num1", "num2"]
```

Comment: This is an issue for me ion Node 16, your solution worked.

Comment: @RayFoss Is this issue at nodejs 14, too? Could you provide us with a source? The strange thing: it doesn't works on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgBIFMCecDewCQAHArgEbgCWoc0ALpBaXJAFzkUBOxAdgObb5G2XW0CjSq07dCJMvxplQwluy64JfKjPJIKAQQBCAYQAUDJqI4AaOEJOKLc65wCUGbFgoALYtAB0kOAF46F3dPLwJ-SyCPbzIA0BdmTTxmNjhg6GwAX2As0AB7Nmhc8CQvcFyOAwAiAGtUOAAzZlyAWzg3VHpKswApAGUAeQA5LxFFYnqUA36CACskUAovWpRoA2QUB03gIA) of typescriptlang.org.